# Permissions issue when using GNU screen

Tags: python, numpy, ssh, gnu-screen

I am trying to $ssh$ a python programme. The code solves a large set of differential equations, calculates some parameters of interest, and should write these to file using the `numpy` function `npumpy.savetxt`.

This works fine when I remain logged in, but often the calculations take a long time so I would like them to just run in the background while I do more interesting things with my life. I have tried to use `GNU screen`, which again, works fine while logged in, but when I detach the screen and log out the calculation false over with the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "programme.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "/path-to-python/Python/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1022, in savetxt
   fh = open(fname, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'filename.txt'
```

I presume that this is something to do with my files unmounting when I log out of the machine. Does anyone have any experience with this or a similar problem?

Let me know if you need anything clarifying.

ps. So that I could get all the appropriate packages installed, I had to go for a local install of python 3.4.2 -- I don't think this is the cause of the issue, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've found the answer but I am posting this solution because I had the same issue, and other people may be interested in it too.

Once you're in the screen, run your program with sudo : 
`$ sudo python programme.py`

Then you can detach and exit your ssh session without getting any permission error with `numpy.savetxt`.

Comment: Hi, yeah I did solve the problem, though it was slightly different to your solution. So it seems that when you log out of ssh it unmounts your home directory so you can no longer write to it. Presumably sudo gets around this issue, unfortunately I don't have sudo privileges so ended up writing my data to hard disk, which seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission on the 'filename.txt' file. Now there are two ways to get around this,you can either change the permission to 755 for the same file or you can run you code with sudo permission.

Comment: Initially I thought that might be the case, in which case I would be stuffed as I have no admin privileges. But the fact that the code works successfully so long as I am still logged into `ssh` makes me think otherwise. Is that not a bit strange, or am I missing something?